# Want a scene with camera.position.y = 7 to display it in the centre of the canvas

Tags: javascript, three.js, world-coordinates

I want a scene with camera.position.y = 7 to be displayed in the centre of the canvas and not a bit down (*like in the attached 2nd Codepen link*).

Here are two simple Three.js Codepen examples:

**1st Example:**
Codepen link: [Link](https://codepen.io/msanjeetaxioned/pen/eYKvBjO)

`camera.position.y = 7; camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);`

In the above demo I have a bar added to the centre of the canvas (*by default*) and I have set camera at y = 7. I have also added camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0). So the camera looks at centre. The output as you can see appears tilted (*the bar appears as if it's falling to the front*) and is not what I expect.

**2nd Example:**
Codepen link: [Link](https://codepen.io/msanjeetaxioned/pen/bGKqBxm)

`camera.position.y = 7;`

The 2nd example is same as first except the camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0) is not added. So the camera looks at y=7. The output is good and is what I want but it is not vertically centered.

**What I what?**
I want the output same as in the 2nd example but it should be displayed in the centre (*both vertically & horizontally*) of the canvas. Also the *camera.position.y* can be anything and not just 7.

Basically the output should appear like in the 2nd example but in the centre of the canvas and for any given value of *camera.position.y*.

Is that achievable?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered to give the scene the same height as your camera? Meaning `scene.position.y = 7;`.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you want the perspective as if the camera is above the bar, but you want the bar to be in the center of the canvas? Perhaps you could employ [`WebGLRenderer.setViewport`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setViewport) to set the renderable area to a position that will capture the bar in the center (note that the `x,y` value may actually put the viewport partially outside the _canvas_ bounds, but think of it more like pointing a camera in a direction a saying specifically what projected area should be captured.

Comment: @Mugen87 Thanks for the reply. This is what I want :
https://codepen.io/msanjeetaxioned/pen/OJExLxy

I have done what the 2nd comment says. I have changed the visible viewport area but due to this the entire bar is not displayed. The bar gets cut.

Comment: @TheJim01 Thanks for the reply. You have understood what I want. But when I do that
https://codepen.io/msanjeetaxioned/pen/OJExLxy

If I change the displayed viewport area only a part of bar is displayed. In the above codepen I have given y = 200 offset to viewport.

Is there a way so the bar is displayed completely?

Comment: I don't think `setViewport` is the solution; that says "draw only on this part of the page."  What you want to do is move the center of the camera's actual view away from the center of the page.  Try changing the viewport call to `camera.setViewOffset( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, 0, 150, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );`.  Whatever y-offset you use will probably have the be added to the total camera height (the second parameter).